# C++ STL wrong keys types

Tags: c++, stl, types, dictionary, key

can't understand this: g++ compiler is angry on:

```
lengths.insert(pair<Deux,long>(d,one));
```

where

```
struct Deux {long big; long small};
map<Deux, long> lengths;
Deux d;
long one;
```

so, g++ said, that i miss `operator<`. after making overloaded `operator<` for `struct Deux`, i saw new interesting, but the same error:

```
map <long, Node*>ArrayOfNodes;
map <long, Node*>::iterator it;  
  for (it=ArrayOfNodes[Root]->nodes.begin();it<ArrayOfNodes[Root]->nodes.end();++it)
      cout<<it->first<<endl;
```

also used structure Node:

```
struct Node {
   long name;
   long guest;
   map <long,Node*>nodes;
/*bool operator<(const Node& node)const{
 if ((*this).name<node.name) return true;
 if ((*this).name>node.name) return false;
  return (*this).guest<(*this).guest;
}*/
```

and error is:

```
    no match for operator< in it < ((Path*)this)->Path::ArrayOfNodes.
 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = long int, _Tp = Node*,
 _Compare = std::less<long int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const long int, Node*> >]
 (((const long int&)((const long int*)(&((Path*)this)->Path::Root))))->Node::nodes.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::end 
 [with _Key = long int, _Tp = Node*, _Compare = std::less<long int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const long int, Node*> >]()
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: Why don't you update your question to show us actual code and the actual compiler error message?

Comment: sorry, my internet connection fall down. okay, thank you, problem with this overload operator< was solved

Comment: @loldop: We invested time to guess your problem. The least you can do is to update your post so that others can learn from it. Otherwise, stackoverflow might not be for you and you'd prefer paid support instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler complains that there is no `operator <` for `Deux` (I guess). The key must be a comparable class with `operator <` or you must pass a third template parameter to map - the comparator.

You see, the map keeps its keys in an ordered way. In order to order them, it needs a predicate. By default it tries to use `operator <`

try writing something like this:

```
bool operator < (Deux const & d1, Deux const & d2)
{
   if(d1.big > d2.big)
      return false;
   if(d1.big < d2.big)
     return true;
   return d1.small < d2.small;  
}
```

Comment: okay, thank you, so i need something like this:

    bool operator<(const Deux& one, const Deux& two){return one.big<two.big;}

Comment: @loldop: I think my version is more correct because it handles the case when big's are equal

Comment: +1: However, I try to avoid overloading `operator<` unless it makes genuine, intuitive sense to do so (i.e. only in cases where it's meaningful to say that one `T` is "less than" another `T`).  In cases where I'm purely satisfying the requirements of `map`, I typically define my own comparison functor, and specify it when creating my `map`.  But that's just me...

Comment: @Oli No, that's not just you :)

Comment: @Oli: That's a valid point of view, but I personally prefer overloading `operator <`. I don't like explicitly specifying third template argument for map. But that's just me... :)

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention the error message. Always post it!

So, I need to fork my post into two distinct sections.

## Missing Declaration.

```
`error: 'Deux' was not declared in this scope`
```

That's because `Deux` is unknown at the point where you declare the `map<>`.

You need to declare `Deux` *before* `map<Deux, long>`, because `map<Deux, long>` requires the full definition of its parameters.

## Missing Comparator.

```
`error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'`
```

That's because you haven't defined `operator<` for `Deux`.`

If you can define a logical `operator<`, i.e. one that is not arbitrarily chosen for sorting purposes, you could do it like this:

```
// must be in same namespace as Deux
bool operator< (Deux const &lhs, Deux const &rhs) {
    return lhs.foo < rhs.foo;
}
```

If it needs access to non-public members, you can make it a member function:

```
bool operator< (Deux const &rhs) {
    return this->foo < rhs.foo;
}
```

If such comparison would be arbitrary, do as Constantinius suggests.

## Next time

You could have saved us time by posting your actual code or a minimal testcase, as well as by mentioning the error message.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your struct is missing a `compare` function, to make an internal sorting of your `Deux` objects as keys. In a map, they have to be sorted.

This is the definition of `std::map`

```
template < class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key,T> > > class map;
```

So if you define a function like this:

```
bool compare_deux(Deux& a, Deux& b) {
    return a.big < b.big;
}
```

and pass it as a template argument:

```
map <Deux, long, compare_deux> lengths;
```

you should be fine.

Comment: Except that the template argument is a function type, not a function pointer. `compare_deux` should be a class that implements `bool operator()(Deux const&, Deux const&)`.

Comment: A comparison function should also work for `const` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [make_pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/).

```
lengths.insert(make_pair<Deux,long>(d,one));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add yet another reply, here's how I would implement `Deux` to be strictly ordered. We just use lexicographic ordering:

```
struct Deux
{
  long big, small;

  inline bool operator<(const Deux & o) const
  {
    return big < o.big || (!(o.big < big) && small < o.small);
  }
};

std::map<Deux, T> m; // works now!
```

Alternatively, we could have spared ourselves the pain and said:

```
typedef std::pair<long, long> Deux;
std::map<Deux, T> m; // always works, lexicographic compare is provided by default
```

Always best not to reinvent the wheel!

Post a comment if you also want pair hashing using `hash_combine` to use unordered containers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the < operator or pass a comparison function on map creation.

```
struct Deux     
{
  long big; 
  long small

  bool operator < (const Deux &n) const
  {         
    if(big != n.big)
       return big < n.big;
    else
       return small < n.small;
   }
};
```